# help building 6S2P balanced Li-Ion battery pack

Tags: batteries, soldering, lithium-ion, wiring

I'm trying to build a 6S2P balanced Li-Ion battery pack for a quadcopter using LG 18650 HG2 cells with pre-soldered nickel strips (1st image) so that I won't solder directly on the cell's terminals.
[image]
so I have some questions:
1 ) I'll put the cells inside the 2 disassembleable arms so how do you advice to keep them in position (2nd image) and isolate e.g. the gray circled terminals (3rd image)?
[image]
2 ) is this diagram correct or are there better solutions?
[image]
3 ) I'll draw a maximum of 30A continuously, are 16AWG wires enough?

Comment: what do you mean with skipping cell node connections? I connect each of the 6 2P cells couples to the JST. the moment of inertia shouldn't change too much, the battery would be more protected and I'd save space and weight of its support.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. Mainly because the batteries are not able to be cooled in that configuration. The moment of inertia would change a lot since you have a lot of extra mass at the edge of the arms whereas normally it is all bunched up in the center.

Comment: I realized that you were skipping balance nodes because those cells were supposed to be in parallel and deleted my last post.

Comment: temperature shouldn't be a problem because 30A is the draw at 100% throttle , but hovering I'll draw 5A

Comment: in this video it seems to work well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4IMu__vvhk

Comment: I wonder what your battery matching tolerances are ! 1mV? 5mV??  This is a simple model kF, ESR which does not even include memory capacitance. I also wonder what the heat capacity of your balancer is and planned CC rate. I can model tolerance design issues https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omdey.png

Comment: sorry I have no idea of what you are talking about :( I'll solder toghether cells in pairs with about same voltage (+-0.01V) so I should't burn them, and then I'll charge the battery pack using the JST plug for balancing.

Comment: Why do you want to isolate the gray circled terminals?

Comment: because the positive terminal of the 1st bottom left cell should not be connected to the negative terminal of the 2st bottom left cell, or they would be in series, right? So maybe I could isolate all the terminals using shrink tape?

Comment: *2nd bottom left cell